# How to implement load more in RecyclerView using volley's POST method?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

Could you explain to me how I can load 10 items and then 10 more, using the volleyball library?

I have found some old items, but none of them work, maybe it is because of the time since they are from 4 years ago.

Comment: have you done so far? then you can post your code here? and see what we can help

Answer (score 0):

You can go with adding Scrolllistener to RecylcerView:

```
       recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL)
            {
                isScrolling = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            currentItems = manager.getChildCount();
            totalItems = manager.getItemCount();
            scrollOutItems = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if(isScrolling && (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems))
            {
                isScrolling = false;
                getData();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can add a handler to load data's

```
 private void getData(){

 progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int i=0; i<5;i++){

                list.add(Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + "");

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
    },5000);
}
```